# Android Studio's trash

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, android-studio

I use Android Studio long time and had a lot of different versions. 
I found in `C:\Users\user folder` five .AndroidStudio folders.

[image: folders]

Can I remove them without harm? (apart from 1.2 - actual version)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove them without doing any harm. When you launch Android Studio if it doesn't have the folder that it needs it will create one.

It's worth noting that after Android Studio 1.2 is released then the config folder will probably be called .AndroidStudio again. If you are worried about losing your config changes then I wouldn't delete that folder (or at least save a copy).